# How do I send stdout as an attachment via mailx?

Tags: email-attachments, rhel7, mailx

I'd like to send output of multiple commands as attachments and with modern system and mailx I'd prefer to skip uuencode and use simply -a switch, **all inline**. But no matter what combinations I tried I am not able to make this work.

Of course it works to redirect outputs into text files first and send those but that's not what I am looking for.

```
( ls -l ~ | uuencode att0.txt; ls -l /tmp | uuencode att1.txt) | mailx -s "ls" someone@somewhere.org
```

This used to work with older environments but it is very outdated, and modern implementations do not properly understand uuencode, prefering MIME, and turn that into body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
( echo "Subject: ls"; ls -l ~ | uuencode att0.txt; ls -l /tmp | uuencode att1.txt) | sendmail someone@somewhere.org
```

Ugly, but working. What you can do.